# Laravel Language changer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I add localization to my laravel app. I define language in my routes.

```php
Route::group(['prefix' => '{language}/tender', 'middleware' => ['permission:tender-page']], function () {
    Route::get('/', 'TenderController@index')->name('tender');
    Route::get('/add', 'TenderController@add')->name('tender_add');
    Route::get('/{id}', 'TenderController@detail')->name('tender_detail');
});
```

I try to change languages by this way

```xml
<li class="nav-item">
    <a href="{{ route(Route::currentRouteName(), 'ru') }}" class="nav-link">RU</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item">
    <a href="{{ route(Route::currentRouteName(), 'tr') }}" class="nav-link">TR</a>
</li>
```

but if i use this way, this kind of routes `Route::get('/{id}', 'TenderController@detail')->name('tender_detail');` got error.

How can realize language changer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the `{id}` parameter again.

```php
{{ route(Route::currentRouteName(), ['language' => 'ru', 'id' => $tender_id]) }}
```

You need to get your current route parameters and override the `{language}`. You can accomplish this by getting the current route's parameter array with `Route::current()->parameters()` and then using `array_merge` to override the language.

```php
{{ route(Route::currentRouteName(), array_merge(Route::current()->parameters(), ['language' => 'ru']) ) }}
```

Comment: There is a lot of ID, i can not pass only one of them

Comment: Your error says you're using the route `tender_detail`. This route expects the two parameters `{language}` and `{id}`. (`[URI: {language}/tender/{id}]`)

Comment: Yes it is, is there any ways to solve it? Maybe another ways to change language

Comment: I think you can make this work: `route(Route::currentRouteName(), array_merge(Route::current()->parameters(), ['language' => 'ru']))`. I'll edit it in my answer.

Comment: It solve an error but dont work correctly, when i am on **http://127.0.0.1:8000/ru/tender/1** page and switch the language link throws me on **http://127.0.0.1:8000/ru/tender?id=1**. **http://127.0.0.1:8000/ru/tender?id=1** view is equal to **http://127.0.0.1:8000/ru/tender**

Comment: Weird. If it's appending the parameter like that, maybe it's getting the wrong route.